# store variant value in object property of TStringList

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

i need store a variant value in a `TStringList`, so far i try this

```
var
 list : TStringList;
 v   : OleVariant;

  List..AddObject('Item1',v);
```

or

```
  List..AddObject('Item1',TObject(v));
```

but in both  cases the code not compile because the typecast is invalid or the types are incompatibles.

so the question is, how i can store  a variant value in a TStringlist ?

Comment: Do you actually need the special features of a TStringList, or do you just need a string-to-OleVariant map?  If the latter, I'd recommend a `TDictionary<string, OleVariant>` instead of a TStringList.  It'll save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: sorry mason but i am using Delphi 2007, i updated the tags. i need store in a list a name and a variant value, i knew which i can write my own class to do this, but i prefer use a really made solution.

Comment: Life is just so much easier with D2010/XE where you can use generic collection classes to deal with all the lifetime issues that this question raises.

Comment: I knew that, but some of my customers dont have the money necesary to pay to EMB the expensive price of Delphi XE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the only way would be to wrap your variant in a class and put a reference to that in the object of the stringlist item. You would of course need to take care that the wrapper instances are properly freed when freeing the stringlist. Using the recent Delphi version's that would easily be done by using the "OwnsObjects" parameter of the stringlist.

Comment: Well, it's not the *only* way, but it's probably the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to store the address of the variant record:

```
List..AddObject('Item1',TObject(@v));
```

Comment: What's with the down vote? This will work and you just have to do this to get the variant back:   ptr :POleVariant;
  ptr := POleVariant(a.Objects[0]);

Comment: Variants are managed types and can contain references. What's going to look after that aspect?

Comment: I never said my answer was the best way to do this. I just answered the question. However, I believe, but haven't tried, that Delphi manages the references correctly

Comment: @Steve It can only take care of the references if you stay within the type system. The explicit cast to TObject takes you outside the realm of the type system.

Comment: -1. You've given a risky answer without mentioning any risks. For instance, you haven't mentioned that the *variable* needs to remain in scope for the lifetime of the list object. You also haven't mentioned any precaution about what would happen if you ran your line of code in a loop. The hint attached to the down-vote button says "This answer is not useful." It says nothing about correctness. Although your answer of how to store a Variant in a TStringList is *correct*, it's not *useful* because so much can go wrong.

Comment: @Rob: Agreed, and I'd even go so far as to say it's *not* correct without at least some treatment of the things that can go wrong and how to deal with or avoid them.